# Xamarin forms Emulator is not starting

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a problem that when I try to run a project on Xamarin Forms, the window immediately closes, what could be the problem, before that everything was working fine.

I had a hint to download intel haxm downloaded it after that it doesn't start at all

Comment: You can only use Hyper-V or HAXM, but not both at the same time. Are you getting any error messages in the console? Make sure to disable Hyper-V completely if you want to use HAXM. Otherwise, uninstall HAXM again and try using Hyper-V.

Comment: I deleted haxm and it says visual studio: This emulator does not have hardware acceleration enabled, and its perfomance will be impacted. Again it recommends me to install intel haxm

Comment: Maybe you should follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration